При повторной записи данных в файл, файл повреждается
У меня есть код который сохраняет голосовое сообщение из Telegram в файл на компьютере для последующей обработки, но проблема возникает когда я перезаписываю этот файл.
По всей видимости после записи в файл, он почему-то не закрывается, из-за чего и возникают последующие ошибки.
Дабы решить данную проблему, пытался обойтись без with, используя самую обычную конструкцию: f.open() и f.close(). Но даже так, выдает ошибку.
Ниже приведу код и ошибку, которая возникает при открытии файла, а также при попытке удалить его.
PS: Использую библиотеку telebot
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['voice'])
def get_voice(message):
    file = bot.get_file(message.voice.file_id)
    bytes = bot.download_file(file.file_path)
    with open('file/voice/voice.ogg', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(bytes)




Ну для начала логичный вопрос — почему вы решили, что файл повреждён? Из фразы «неподдерживаемые параметры кодировки» это никак не следует

Это лишь предположение. А сделал я его потому что при первой записи файла все проходит отлично и все работает, но когда я повторно записываю данные в файл, он перестает открываться

Логичный вопрос — те же самые данные? Если не те же самые, то вполне логично, что другой файл может иметь другой формат и не поддерживаться

Формат данных тот же самый. Расширение ".ogg" - формат для голосовых сообщений telegram

ogg — это контейнер, внутри которого может быть какой угодно формат, в том числе и неподдерживаемый вашей системой

А то, что вы уклонились от прямого ответа на вопрос, намекает на то, что данные всё-таки не те же самые, а значит ваше предположение ничем внятным не обосновано

Ну тогда вопрос: почему при первой записи данных, файл спокойно открывается и воспроизводится?

Так как вы не озаботились записью тех же самых данных, то в таких условиях текущий ответ — потому что первый раз вы записываете файл поддерживаемого формата, а второй раз — файл неподдерживаемого формата. А чтобы уверенно утверждать, что файл повреждается, вам нужно как-то доказать, что файл действительно повреждается — ну например хотя бы попытаться прочитать его обратно и проверить, прочиталось ли в точности то же самое, что и записалось, или не то же самое if open(..., 'rb').read() != bytes: print('ну и чо за хрень')

Я немного не понимаю ваших претензий. У меня есть файл "voice.ogg" в который я записываю представление голосового сообщения в виде байтов. Данные разные, потому что содержание голосового сообщения не совпадает, но формат тот же самый и он явно должен поддерживаться

«но формат тот же самый и он явно должен поддерживаться» — вы это всё тоже не доказали, оттого и претензии

Что в первом, что во втором случае, я скачиваю голосовое сообщение с одного и того же ресурса. с одинаковыми расширениями и одинаковым способом. Так что вплоне логично что формат должен быть одинаковый. Также, если каждый раз генерировать новые названия файлов при сохранении, то они все открываются и воспроизводятся, но как только я перезаписываю данные в уже существующем файле, он ломается

«если каждый раз генерировать новые названия» — во, вот это уже что-то толковое. Тут уже можно начинать теоретизировать — например, не оказывается ли случайно так, что вы в коде вешаете второй обработчик и бот начинает пытаться записать файл два раза одновременно. Но, пока в вопросе отсутствует [mcve], ответить что-то внятное вряд ли получится

Может вы не работали с telebot, попытаюсь объяснить что происходит в коде (не умею пользоваться возможностями stackoverflow для редактирования текста, так что так).
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['voice']) - данная строчка ждет пока в чате с ботом не появится голосовое сообщение. Как только оно появляется, начинает работать функция get_voice(message) которая сохраняет это голосовое ко мне на компьютер

Переменная file по сути это данные о голосовом сообщении, а bytes это содержание файла. Думаю все объяснил

Пока в вопросе отсутствует [mcve], не имеет никакого значения, работал я с telebot или нет — в коде, который вы не показали, может твориться какая угодно дичь, а в коде, который вы показали, никаких очевидных ошибок не видно (иначе бы я претензий и не высказывал), так что ответить по существу сейчас трудно

В том и проблема, что я тоже не вижу в данном коде проблемы, но она там есть, В остальном коде я больше никак не взаимодействую с голосовыми сообщениями. Если вам так будет проще, могу добавить в вопрос код основного файла
